# Sharepoint/Angular 403 Error - Should the FormDigestValue be an hour old when issued?

Tags: angular, rest, sharepoint

I have created a sharepoint online add-in with a list (LearningsList) which i want to access from an embedded Angular app.

Listing the content of the list works fine, however when trying to add an item to the list I get a 403 forbidded access error.

I have tried connecting to the contextinfo and retrieving an up to date FormDigestValue (which it returns fine) however this still doesn't work.

The only issue I can see is that the FormsDigestValue date/time is always an hour later than my local time.  Could this be the issue?

I have admin rights and can manually add items fine.

```
  var restUrl = '/SharePointAddIn3/_api/contextinfo';
  let headers2 = new HttpHeaders(
    {
    'Accept':'application/json;odata=verbose'
    }
    );

return this.http.post(restUrl,{}, headers2)
  .subscribe(
    res => {
      console.log(res);

      console.log("Started onSubmitSP: digest result=" + res.FormDigestValue);


      var restUrl = '/SharePointAddIn3/_api/lists/LearningsList/items';

      var digest = res.FormDigestValue;

      console.log("Started onSubmitSP: digest:" + digest);




      return this.http.post(restUrl,
        JSON.stringify(
          { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.ListFieldsContentType' }, 'Title': 'Test'}
        ), 

        {
          'X-RequestDigest' : digest, 
          'accept':"application/json;odata=verbose",
          'content-type':"application/json;odata=verbose"
        })

      .subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(res);
          console.log("Success!!! added the record:");
          this.submitted = true;
        },
        err => {
          console.log("Error occured saving:");
          console.log(err);
        }

      );





    },
    err => {
      console.log("Error occured");
    }
  )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue was in the way I was providing the headers.  They should have been labeled as headers so like this:

```
{
     headers {
      'X-RequestDigest' : digest, 
      'accept':"application/json;odata=verbose",
      'content-type':"application/json;odata=verbose"
       }
    }
```

Rather than this:

```
{
      'X-RequestDigest' : digest, 
      'accept':"application/json;odata=verbose",
      'content-type':"application/json;odata=verbose"
    }
```